# Has Blob Ever Been Shown to Be Injured by Electrocution?

Tags: marvel, x-men

One of the main reasons I have started to wonder about this recently, is I can't find any instances of this happening, although I imagine that there are several characters who could use electrocution as a means of assault. Can anyone help?

Comment: It has to be pointed out that in the 1958 B-movie _[The Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blob)_,  which undoubtedly  inspired this character, a live wire falling on the monster didn't faze it at all -- it took something completely different  to stop it.

Comment: Do you mean Fred "The Blob" Dukes, enemy of the X-Men or the movie monster? (I'm assuming by the tags, you mean the Marvel character, but just making sure)

Comment: @Mgmills1968-Fred "The Blob" Dukes, not the movie monster, actually forgot about that film

Comment: What version of Fred Dukes ? He has been in movies, cartoons and of course comics.

Comment: @BjornEriksson-Any version will work, although I don't think you'll get much luck from the movies side, since he's only been in X-Men: Origins: Wolverine, fighting Logan and had a brief cameo early in X-Men: Apocalypse where he gets knocked out by Angel (which, sorry, that ain't happening, Blob beats Warren every time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in [Wolverine and the X-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_and_the_X-Men_(TV_series)), Storm shocks him a couple of times and he falls:

This is episode #8 "Time Bomb" and it happens towards the end of the episode, when they’re fighting on the ice.

Comment: Hey, sorry it took me a while to accept, i thought i already had. Computer must have glitched out